# Why isn't OpenVZ in the Linux kernel by default?

Tags: linux, openvz

Does anyone know why OpenVZ hasn't been merged into the official Linux kernel?

Right now you have to download a special kernel from openvz.org

Comment: ...Linus Torvalds?

Comment: Just a comment not an answer as I have nothing to do with kernel development.  My geuss is because lxc is in the kernel and they are very simular.  http://lxc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Nunya, about [Lxc and OpenVZ](http://openvz.livejournal.com/30998.html?thread=97046#t97046)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some parts OpenVZ were merged into the official kernel but not enough to run OpenVZ. So you do need a separately patched kernel.

The best way to install an OpenVZ is through a package manager. On CentOS / RedHat variants you probably will need to add some external repositories. On Debian stable (6.0) the OpenVZ kernel image is in the official repository and gets security patches.

Even though it's in mainstream Debian (who use the official Linux branch), it seems that OpenVZ team prefers to stick more closely to the RHEL branch.

Comment: So they are working on getting all of OpenVZ into mainline kernel?

Comment: I don't think that is forseeable right now, but the more gets accepted into the kernel the better.

Comment: @Sandra, yes they are working on getting all of the OpenVZ into the mainline Linux.